# Spyder4 button icons' appearance unnormally

Tags: python, spyder

[icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1D3f.png)

Does anyone met the similar problem before? I installed it by anaconda and I tried to uninstall and reinstall it but it does not work, how could I solve it?

Comment: I know that is not only for you. Try to go to `Tools>Preferences>General>Appearance` and change your icon theme. At least, this is the path in Spyder 3.3.6.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please update to the latest QtAwesome version and try again.